# Runtime error 13 on a simple update query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The simple query below is returning a Runtime error 13.  Doing a simple check on the internet the feedback seems to be that I may be some type of bug in MS Access which requires an update..  Is it possible? This type of query I have used time and time again in the same database where it currently sits.

```
st_Sql = "INSERT INTO tblCompetency05 ( CompetencyID ) SELECT tblCompetency03.ID FROM tblCompetency03 WHERE (((tblCompetency03.Flag)<>'OK'))"
Application.DoCmd.RunCommand (st_Sql)
```

Comment: Did you check you mdb file size?

Comment: Can you also add your error description? and type of your fields like `CompetencyID`, `tblCompetency03.ID` and `tblCompetency03.Flag`?, Please ;).

Comment: Why should the file type size make a difference? What i can confirm is that the database file size did not chance recently Always remaining around 90 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, this code seems to resolve my problem but from a syntax point of view, I still don't understand why.

```
st_Sql = "INSERT INTO tblCompetency05 ( CompetencyID ) SELECT tblCompetency03.ID FROM tblCompetency03 WHERE [tblcompetency03].[Flag]<>'OK'"
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_Sql)
```

Comment: I think `Flag` should be a reserved word in Access ;).

Comment: [RunCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194612.aspx) is an entirely different operation than [RunSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626.aspx) The former calls an action from the Access VBA library while the latter calls the JET/ACE SQL engine to perform action queries or data definition queries. They are not interchangeable.